# Invalid literal for Decimal: u'3,982.75'

Tags: django

I'm having trouble with a localized form field not accepting localized input. Entering a number with a comma as a decimal separator triggers a validation error. How to fixed it? How to make that value valid for decimal field?

Here's my sample models.py

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2, default="0.00")
```

In my views.py where the error trigger:

```
def manual_opening(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       opening_bal = request.POST.get('opening_bal')
       form = AddBankAccountForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.cleaned_data['balance'] = Decimal(opening_bal)
           .....
```

When my user input a value, for ex. 3,485.78, for their opening_bal. The system trigger an error that the Decimal function not allow the operation because the number has a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A google search has revealed the truth!
[Format Localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/formatting/)

```
revenue = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, localize=True)
```

Comment: You also need to add `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True` to `settings.py`